# Warning C4047, pointers to function

Tags: pointers

I need some help on this:
while compiling, i keep getting **error 4047**

`warning C4047: 'return' : 'int (__cdecl *)(const char *,...)'`

differs in levels of indirection from `'int *'`

How am I able to get rid of this issue?

```
    int (*GetPrintfPointer(void))(const char *format, ...) 
    {
       int *pPrintf;
       pPrintf = (int *)printf;
       return pPrintf;
    }


    int (*GetPutsPointer(void))(const char *str)
    {
       int *pPuts; 
       pPuts = (int *)puts;
       return pPuts;
    }
```

Comment: what is the function supposed to return?

Comment: Clearly your function takes int as return and not int*

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
int f(const char *){
    return 1;
}

int (*GetPutsPointer(void))(const char *str)
{
   return f;
}
```

for you `f` is either `puts` or `printf`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It simple when you use a typedef:

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef int (*pPrintf)(const char*,...);
typedef int (*pPuts)(const char*);

pPrintf getPrintf(void)
{
    return &printf;
}
//or if this is what you've tried to do:
int* getPrintfAsIntPointer(void)
{
    return (int*)&printf;
}

pPuts getPuts()
{
    return &puts;
}

int main()
{
    getPrintf()("%s\n","hello world");
    getPuts()("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the less readable prototype (without using a typedef for the return value) for `getPuts()` is: `int (*getPuts(void))(const char*);`. Clearly using a typedef is the way to go.